# Checking for all lowercase & Combining a Word with a List - Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am having some trouble writing 2 separate functions. One of which "isWord s" is to take in a word and return "true" if all characters of the word are lowercase, otherwise return "false". Below is an example:

```
isWord "foo" = True; isWord "fo3o" = False
```

It must use this definition:

```
isWord :: String -> Bool
isWord s =
```

The other function "prefixWords str strs" which takes a word and a list of words and combines the two in a list with a ":" between each word. Shown below as an example:

```
prefixWords "word:" ["aa", "a3", "foo"] = ["word:aa", "word:foo"]
```

It must use this definition:

```
prefixWords :: String -> [String] -> [String]
prefixWords str strs =
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I am brand new to Haskell and don't have any idea of where to start. Thanks!

Comment: You need the functions [`all`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=all) and [`map`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=map).

Comment: Yes that's one thing I forgot to mention. We're given that we can use all, map, and filter.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is clearly homework, I won't give you the answers, just a large nudge.

First off, `String` is just a synonym for `[Char]`.

These functions may be helpful:

```
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

This will concatenate two lists or strings.

```
import Data.Char
isLower :: Char -> Bool
```

This will test if a `Char` is lowercase or not

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
```

This will test whether or not all of a lists elements satisfy a predicate.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

This applies a function to all elements of a list.

For your function `isWord`, you need to check that `all` of a strings elements are/`isLower`.

For your function `prefixWords`, every element is concatenated with a given string.